# How to filter content of resultset in java

Tags: java, resultset

I have a scenario like this :
I have a website that users send range of date for example `2013-01-01` to `2013-01-04` and then I need to get some information from the database for each day in a range for example in the above scenario I have to send request to database 3 times:

```
2013-01-01 to 2013-01-02,2013-01-02 to 2013-01-03,2013-01-03 to 2013-01-04
```

so as you can see if I want to extract for a month then this would take so long. A better and faster Idea is to call database once and extract all information , for example this range  `2013-01-01` to `2013-01-04`, all at once and filter information according to each day in java.

Is there anyway that I can do that in java with the help of result set? I appreciate also if anyone has a better idea to handle this scenario ?

**Update :**

Here is the query that I am using :

```
SELECT enID, sum(frequency) from entity-epoch
WHERE dateID IN(
    SELECT dateid
    WHERE startdate>=2013-01-01 AND enddate<=2013-01-02)
GROUP BY sum(frequency)
```

and I have a loop thatcall it for each day?(instead of thoes dates above that I put for better readability I have ? and feed it with different dates.

Comment: Is the information aggregatable?  This sort of thing is what databases are good at.  If it suits the data you're pulling out, you can use "group by dateColumn".

Comment: Why the nested query? Why not just `SELECT enID, sum(frequency)
WHERE startdate>=2013-01-01 AND enddate<=2013-01-02
GROUP BY sum(frequency)`?

Comment: Because unfortunately the actual dates are in another table and now it is too late to change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better idea still is to only fetch the data you actually want to process, via a suitable WHERE clause.

Comment: Yes I can retrieve the data but I can not separate data according to day( I can not use group by on date) and if I want to fetch the data that I need in a way that you said for each day in the range I need to call database in a loop which seems time consuming

Comment: @HamedMinaee It is always better to fetch less, and to fetch what you want when you want it, otherwise you can be dealing with stale data. I suggest you reconsider your queries. You can always *sort* by day if necessary, that 'separates' it enough.

Answer (score 2):

As @EJP suggested, you are most likely better off only pulling the data that you actually need, rather than consuming extra lines and cycles pulling it all then processing it.

This is especially true if you are pulling the data using `SELECT *`, because future changes to the database schema can have potentially deleterious effects on your program's logic. This actually came up recently on the [programmers exchange site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/234657/why-is-select-from-table-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Yes I can retrieve the data but I can not separate data according to days( I can not use group by on date) and if I want to fetch the data that I need in a way that you said for each day in the range I need to call database in a loop which seems time consuming

Comment: I think we need more information about the structure of your database and expected user input in order to provide more specific advice.